# How to add a button to each event in fullcalendar v5? I am using listWeek view

Tags: javascript, html, flask, fullcalendar

[Here is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0If6.png)

(the button was edited via inspect element by me) I've been trying to implement it by using eventRender without any luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.js"></script> </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.css"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
  <script>
    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'listDay',
      views: {
      listDay: {
        type:'listWeek',
        dayCount:1
        }
      },
      events : [
        {% for appointment in appointments %}
        {
          title : '{{ appointment[2] }}',
          start : '{{ appointment[1] }}',
        },
        {% endfor %}
      ],
      eventRender: function(info) {
      info.el.innerHTML += "<button class='dayButton' data-date='" + info.start + "'>Click me</button>";
      info.el.style.padding = "20px 0 0 10px";
      }
    });
    calendar.render();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The old `eventRender` callback doesn't exist in fullCalendar 5.x. Instead, use one of the [event render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks)

Comment: BTW what do you want the button to do? You might be better to simply handle [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) then the user can click anywhere on the event, and whatever action you wish can be performed.

Answer (score 2):

At the end I solved by doing this :

```
  eventContent: function (args, createElement)
  {
    const text = args.event._def.title + '<button onclick="alert(\'hello\')" style="float: right"> ciao </button>';
    return {
    html: text
  };
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).