# How to add remove event option with cross sign in fullcalendar.io ? asp.net mvc core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am going to add `remove cross sign` with each event of calendar which are getting from database. But how to add this and i want when click on cross sign(delete) then specific url will be triggered and i want to delete event from database. Please let me know how can i do this? How to add delete event with cross sign.

**call-init.js**

```
  !function($) {
   "use strict";

var CalendarApp = function() {
    this.$body = $("body")
    this.$calendar = $('#calendar'),
    this.$event = ('#calendar-events div.calendar-events'),
    this.$categoryForm = $('#add-new-event form'),
    this.$extEvents = $('#calendar-events'),
    this.$modal = $('#my-event'),
    this.$saveCategoryBtn = $('.save-category'),
    this.$calendarObj = null
};

  /* Initializing */
CalendarApp.prototype.init = function() {
    this.enableDrag();
    /*  Initialize the calendar  */
    var events = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: '/Booking/GetBookings',
        success: function (mems) {
            
             //states contains the JSON formatted list
             //of states passed from the controller
            $.each(mems, function (_, member) {
                debugger;
                events.push({

                    title: member.guestname,
                    start: new Date(member.checkindatetime),
                    end: new Date(member.checkoutdatetime),
                    allDay: true,
                    url: '/Booking/Booking/' + member.encryptedId,
                    className: member.classnamecolor
                   
                });

                
            });


        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Buchungen konnten nicht geladen werden.');
        }
    });
           var $this = this;
    $this.$calendarObj = $this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'month',  
        handleWindowResize: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },

       
        navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        events: events
        //eventStartEditable: false // disable drag&drop of events
    });
},

 //init CalendarApp
$.CalendarApp = new CalendarApp, $.CalendarApp.Constructor = CalendarApp

}(window.jQuery),

//initializing CalendarApp
function($) {
"use strict";
$.CalendarApp.init()
}(window.jQuery);
```

**other calendar view is**

```
@model FewoVerwaltung.Models.Booking.BookingListModel
 
 <div id="calendar"></div>
 <!-- Calendar JavaScript -->
<script src="~/plugins/calendar/dist/locale/de.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/calendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/plugins/calendar/dist/cal-init.js"></script>
```

Comment: What "cross sign" are you referring to?

Comment: for delete, please check updated question now.

Comment: Hi, hameed! Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605850/how-to-add-a-button-to-each-event-in-fullcalendar-v5-i-am-using-listweek-view/72613536)... I bet it will be useful for you. The short answer is... using **eventContent** hook. I'm talking about FullCalendar v5.

Comment: Hi @VFG, you are right thanks, i already see it but i dont know how to use and where to use in code, i am beginner, please help me, send my code on answer with updated

Comment: It should be wherever you set-up your FullCalendar (CalendarApp?)  The code you wrote is the place where you populate an array of events. After that, you assign somewhere else those `events` to your FullCalendar, but I cannot know where is that, as far as I read the code you posted

Comment: Hi @VFG I have updated code now, please check

Comment: I can't help if I can't see the structure of your application, but have a look to this example... https://github.com/esausilva/fullcalendar-aspnet-core ||| You have the key I'm talking about for your answer in https://github.com/esausilva/fullcalendar-aspnet-core/blob/master/fullcalendar-core/Scripts/calendar.js

Comment: And please, remember that this is just an example because it uses a previous version of FullCalendar, not v5

Comment: You haven't shown us how you actually initialise fullCalendar itself. Event content hooks go into the calendar options.

Comment: Hi @ADyson please check updated code, i have add initialise fullCalendar at the end of code.

Comment: No, that's not it - and you've already got $.CalendarApp.init() at the top of the script anyway. We're talking about some **fullCalendar** initialisation code like in one of the examples linked from here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getting-started

Comment: Please @ADyson check now full code,

Comment: No that's still not it. All you've shown us is a script tag which includes the fullCalendar library code in your page. That simply makes fullCalendar functionality available, but it doesn't actually cause a calendar to be created in your page. Did you look at the examples? Unless you're using one of the Angular/Vue/React connections then we're looking for code which includes `new FullCalendar.Calendar` or perhaps `new Calendar`

Comment: I am using asp.net core, and its full code, view contains this and its incldues these files,

Comment: please @ADyson check code carefully above its mentioned this code  `var $this = this;
    $this.$calendarObj = $this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'month',  
        handleWindowResize: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },`

Comment: Thanks. `$this.$calendar.fullCalendar` is the bit I was talking about, although the appearance is slightly different.... can I check, which version of fullCalendar you're using? The solution may be slightly different in each case. I suspect you're using v3 which is very old now - any reason you chose to use that? v5 is much better in various ways.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson much appreciated that you are helping me, thanks, here i have check file `fullcalendar.min.js` its mentioned this version on top file ` FullCalendar v3.4.0
 Docs & License: https://fullcalendar.io/
 (c) 2017 Adam Shaw`

Comment: @ADyson i have not used this, my client have old developer and its old application so i think previous developer use this old one, because its old app, all application working fine expect delete even, i just want to add `delete` sign with each event and when click on `cross` icon then popup will show to delete event from database.

Comment: Ok. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc is the documentation for that version, for your reference. So, you _could_ use [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventRender) to add the cross icon into the event's HTML and attach an event handler to it. But if you don't want to do any other actions when clicking on an event, it might be simple to just use [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventClick) instead and open your popup from that callback instead. Then fullCalendar handles the click event for you, and the user can click anywhere on the event to activate it.

Comment: P.S. At very least you should upgrade the fullCalendar library files to the latest 3.x version to get bug fixes (everything else will still be compatible). 3.4 is a very early update in that branch and likely has some issues. You can still get every version from the [releases](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases) page of the fullCalendar site. It looks like [3.10.2](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v3.10.2) was the last update to 3.x.

Comment: Yes you right and thanks for explanation, but i am beginner, and i don't know where to add these lines of `evenRender` code etc, please help me, add your answer, i will try

Comment: You have to add it into the fullCalendar options, as I said. It's an option, just like `defaultView`, `header` etc. There's even an example, right there in the documentation I gave you. Please try something, the best way to learn is by doing. If you get stuck, post your attempt and explain the specific issue you're facing.

Comment: But as I said, eventClick will be easier to use - start with that, rather than messing about trying to get HTML buttons into the rendered event.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, i am trying, but on click i am already using `url` to move to other page for update, so i want to use other option on click `cross sign`

Comment: @ADyson i am using this code but its not working  ` var $this = this;
        $this.$calendarObj = $this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'month',  
            handleWindowResize: true,
                       eventRender: function (events, $el) {
                $el.popover({
                    title: events.title,
                    content: events.start,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement: 'top',
                    container: 'body'
                });
            },`

Comment: Not working how exactly? Error? Unexpected behaviour? Did you follow the link to the live demo and make sure you included the relevant JS libraries and CSS code too? If you're going to copy and paste something off the internet you have to make sure you have some understanding of it, just blindly copying is never a good strategy.

Comment: p.s. If you have further updates, you should [edit] your question - code in comments is not easy to read, and also this isn't a discussion forum - the comments should be just for brief clarification requests, really.